# Is there a way to use `pivot_wider()` to summarize survey data?

Tags: r, dplyr

I have a bunch of survey data, something like:
I have some survey data, let's say it's about how often respondents tackle various daily routines:

```
survey <- tribble(
~Q1_toothbrush, ~Q1_bathe, ~Q1_brush_hair, ~Q1_make_bed,
"Always","Sometimes","Often","Never",
"Never","Never","Always","Sometimes",
"Often","Sometimes","Sometimes","Often",
"Sometimes","Always","Often","Never"
)
```

I want to arrange it into a table that shows how many people selected "Often" or "Always".

I can create a new tibble and update it, taking each question one at a time, eg.

```
  habits <- tribble(
    ~Habit, ~Description, ~Count,
    "Q1_toothbrush", "Brushes teeth for two minutes twice each daty.", 0,
    "Q1_bathe", "Bathes with soap and water every morning or evening", 0,
    "Q1_hair", "Attends to daily hair health", 0,
    "Q1_make_bed", "Tidies bed covers daily", 0
  ) 
  
  top_two <- c("Always", "Often")
  
  tmp <- survey %>% 
    filter(Q1_toothbrush %in% top_two) %>%
    count()
  
  habits <- habits %>% 
    mutate(Count = ifelse(Habit == "Q1_toothbrush", tmp, Count))

  
  kable(habits)
```

But I'm struggling to consolidate this into a single function.

Comment: I just re-ran it and I'm not getting an error.

Comment: sorry, it is a function masking

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If we need to do this for each row, an option is `c_across` after doing `rowwise`

```
library(dplyr) # >= 1.0.0
survey %>% 
    rowwise %>%
    mutate(count = sum(c_across(everything()) %in% top_two)) %>%
    ungroup
```

---

Or we can reshape to 'long' format and then do the `count`

```
library(dplyr)
library(tidyr)
pivot_longer(survey, everything()) %>%
      filter(value %in% top_two) %>%
      dplyr::count(name)
```

Comment: And then I can group and count: `pivot_longer(survey, everything()) %>% filter(value %in% top_two) %>% group_by(name) %>% count()`

Comment: @Amanda if you need the `name` to be count, then remove the `value` from it i.e `count(name)`